# Using git, how can I create a mostly history-less clone of a repository

Tags: git, repository, revision-history

I have a 2 year old repository that started off as essentially a private repository, so it contained in it's history at different points: key files, encryption keys, large sets of images in various places, etc etc, in the history of the repository, all of which are no longer tracked but still exist in the history.

The source is now becoming shared, since we're bringing on new developers, and I want to make a clean start with a mostly clean repository.  However, during this transitional period, I may have to deal with the old repository as well, sharing patches/commits between the two repositories.

What is the best way to break away from the previous history in git and yet retain <strike>backwards compatibility</strike> the ability to share commits between the old repository and the new clean repository, as cleanly as possible?

Objectives:

1. Make sensitive commits in the way past of the history unavailable in
   the new repository.
2. Allow full functionality in the new repository (clone, push, fetch, everything that's normal for git)
3. Maximize the ability for the old repo to recognize patches/commits that come from the new repo
4. [Less important] Make new repo faster due to not having binaries in ancient commits that aren't present in working copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just creating a new, clear branch in your existing repo won't help: If the users could read this branch, they'll also have access to your old branches that contain your sensitive information. To overcome this, you'll have to create a new repo with no (or only limited) knowledge about the past.

To achieve this, I'd do the following:

- Take a relatively new state of your repo (e.g. the last labeled version or something like that, say `V1.0`) and use this as a start to create a **new** repo (`newrepo`) that is used by your new developers.
- Then, on your machine, add a [remote](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-remote) called `oldrepo` that points to the old repository holding the old sensitive data.
- Next, take all commits from `V1.0` until latest from `oldrepo` and [`cherry-pick`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-cherry-pick) them into your new repo. At this point, your new repo has the same state as `oldrepo` without the dirty history.
- Now, [clone](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-clone) a bare repo from `newrepo` (`newrepo.git`). All your developers clone `newrepo.git` and work on it.

If it comes to take patches etc. from `newrepo.git` into `oldrepo` or vice versa, this operation will be done by **you**, i.e. your colleagues send you needed patches generated by `format-patch` and you `am` them into the old repo. If you have some fixes done in `oldrepo`, you could again `cherry-pick` them into `newrepo.git` and make them available to your devs.

This limits the access to `oldrepo` to you and your colleagues will never see any sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try (I don’t know if this works) is to create a separate branch that tracks the new development, which starts off the empty commit (i.e. has no parent) and just got the content copied in. Then you merge that branch back into the old master (by hand). After that you should be able to develop on the new branch and pull in changes from it to the old branch. And you don’t have to publish the old branch to others.

As and image it would like this, where `O` is the original branch, `C` is copy in a new parentless branch, `M` being the manual merge, and `m` being subsequent merges.

```
# -- # -- # -- O --- M ------------ m -- m
                    /              /    /
                   /              /    /
                  C -- # -- # -- # -- # -- #
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, so (to share development) I would have to push to a fresh repository, pushing only that single branch somehow?  Seems like I wouldn't be able to do that because C is just a patch like any other commit, so making a new repository from just that wouldn't work?

Comment: Oh, I see, the content would be copied in by hand, I guess.  Can you suggest how I would create an "empty commit"?

Comment: To create a parent-less commit, set the HEAD manually and reset the index: `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/newbranch` and `rm .git/index`. Then you copy over the content add it to the index and commit which results in `C`. And yeah, you can basically separate the repositories; one is the “public” that only contains childs those starting at `C` and the other one contains also the others, so you push new changes from the public to the other one.

Comment: But wouldn't a `git clone` copy all the repository later on?

Comment: You would only clone the “public” repository that does not contain the old history.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you specifically mean by "backwards compatibility" but you should be able to specify a `--depth 1` argument to `git clone` (as described in the [git-clone man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)) and get something where *patches* can be shared (although *commits* themselves won't be able to be shared via the normal push/pull mechanism you might be used to.

Comment: Clarified "backwards compatibility" to something more like "commit sharing compatibility".  As far as using --depth 1, doesn't that create a crippled repository, kinda?  That page says "A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it)".   Those seem like crippling disadvantages that I definitely want to avoid, since only in the short term will any commits be made to the old repository, and in a month or two all commits and branching, etc etc will be done to the *new* repository.

Answer (score 0):

Use git branch to create a new branch. Then git rebase your first to last commit to have a history-less version of your old branch.

You can always go back to the old branch to get commit specific details.