# Share repo without sharing past commits?

Tags: git, bitbucket

My team has done a silly thing and left passwords in older versions of my readme file, checked into the repo.

**How can I avoid sharing these historic commits when I add a new team member who I don't want to see these passwords?**

All of it is only on one file, but there are hundreds of commits that contain these passwords.

Comment: Fork the repo maybe?

Comment: I think I'd copy all the files to a new folder and make a brand new repo. and share it from there.

Comment: new branch won't do it, only solution is a new repo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297905/using-git-how-can-i-create-a-mostly-history-less-clone-of-a-repository

Comment: There's always the possibility to rewrite the entire history (e.g. see ['The Nuclear Option'](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/872700/1860929

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Comment: Thanks all, the new repo is the way to go here - rewriting history is indeed a bit nuclear and scares me, I want to keep seeing the old history for myself.  I will give it a try.